# F# - type conversion bool to int

Tags: f#, type-conversion

I can't figure out why I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Well, the error text says it all: bool does not support conversion to int. What do you find unclear about that? Try typing `int true` - you'll get the same error.

Comment: He's attempting to define an explicit conversion from `bool` to `int`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've attempted to define an explicit conversion from `bool` to `int`, but extension members cannot currently provide operator overloads (or conversion operators). It looks like there's an [F# language design suggestion](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/RFCs/FS-1043-extension-members-for-operators-and-srtp-constraints.md) to support it in the future, though.

Note: [It's better to paste your actual code into your question, rather than using an image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)